# Extract each line from a cell in the CSV file which has multiple lines

Tags: powershell, csv

I have CSV file which has a column name as Users. That column has 3 line one single cell

Example:

```
Domain\User0
Domain\User1
Domain\Group
```

```
$entry = Import-Csv Input.csv | select -First 1 | %{$_.Users}

$user0 = $entry[0]
$user1 = $entry[1]
$group = $entry[2]
```

I get output as:

```
PS> Write-Host $user0 

Domain\User0
Domain\User1
Domain\Group

PS> Write-Host $user1

PS> Write-Host $group
```

I need output like

```
PS> Write-Host $user0 
Domain\User0

PS> Write-Host $user1
Domain\User1

PS> Write-Host $group
Domain\Group
```

Comment: would you please add the raw CSV file content ...at least the 1st three lines? i can't figure out how you could get what you show ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

Split the field at newlines:

```
$entry = Import-Csv Input.csv |
         Select-Object -First 1 |
         ForEach-Object {$_.Users -split '\r\n' }
```

or simpler:

```
$entry = (Import-Csv Input.csv | Select-Object -Expand Users -First 1) -split '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is going to be a CRLF issue.

```
$entry = ((Get-Content File.csv) -replace "(?<!\r)\n","`r`n" | ConvertFrom-Csv).Users

$user0 = $entry[0]
$user1 = $entry[1]
$group = $entry[2]
```

You will need to replace lines with only the LF character with CRLF and then read from the CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

In case your (valid) `Input.csv` content looks like:

```
> Get-Content .\Input.csv
"Users"
"Domain\User0
Domain\User1
Domain\Group"
```

---

```
$user0,$user1,$group = (Import-Csv Input.csv)[0].Users -split '\r?\n'
```

Will split and directly assign the variables

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
$user0, $user1, $Group=(Import-Csv C:\temp\Input.csv).Users
```